# Encrypt and Decrypt with AES ECB mode 'BadPaddingException' in some cases

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

In android/java app

```
   public static void setKey(String myKey) {

        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = new byte[]{(byte) '5', (byte) 'F', (byte) '8', (byte) 'p', (byte) 'J', (byte) 't', (byte) 'v', (byte) 'U', (byte) 'm', (byte) 'q', (byte) 'k', (byte) '7', (byte) 'A', (byte) 'M', (byte) 'v', (byte) 'b', (byte) 'q', (byte) 'o', (byte) 'H', (byte) 'M', (byte) '9', (byte) 'a', (byte) 'p', (byte) '4', (byte) '9', (byte) 'm', (byte) 'c', (byte) 'u', (byte) 'u', (byte) '5', (byte) 'B', (byte) 'X'};
            System.out.println(new String(key, "UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setEncryptedarr(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            setEncryptedString(String.valueOf(Base64.encode(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT)));
            //setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decryptbyte(byte[] strToDecrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedarr(cipher.doFinal(strToDecrypt));
            System.out.println("encrypt : decropted size : " + getDecryptedarr().length);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error wnhile decrypting: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedarr(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(strToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT)));
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(strToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT))));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I am working on this code : http://aesencryption.net/
I use this snipped code is working well when use it in case of :
encryptbyte and decryptbyte whitch take byte[] 
and I test it it's result of encryption in this site http://aesencryption.net/

**but i need it to decript data came from server (response is came string)
and when I convert the String to byte[] the code always thraw exception :**
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length**

I think it's when covert the String to byte[] it change , if that what is the right way to convert .
Advice please .

This code thraw exception :

```
try {
    AES.setKey("");
    final String strToDecrypt = "tATTXSdXI4w0oiu/fzgpyA==";
    AES.decryptbyte(toBytes(strToDecrypt.toCharArray()));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is the exception

```
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
 01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
01-21 15:24:55.861 15700-15700/ W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: Where is the data? Add some hex dumps and examine them. It will help if you understand various encodings. Also ECB mode is insecure as is a string for a key, that is only appropriate if you want to say you used encryption but do not really want security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it ....
the server encrypt AES with out padding and ZeroBytePadding mode  is the only working mode ...
working code :

```
public class AESCryptt {
    private static final String TAG = "AESCrypt";
    private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/ECB/ZeroBytePadding";
    private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";//
    public static boolean DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED = false;


    private static SecretKeySpec generateKey(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] key = new byte[]{your key in byte here (byte) a, (byte) f , ..... };
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }


    /**
     * Encrypt and encode message using 256-bit AES with key generated from password.
     *
     *
     * @param password used to generated key
     * @param message the thing you want to encrypt assumed String UTF-8
     * @return Base64 encoded CipherText
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if problems occur during encryption
     */
    public static String encrypt(final String password, String message)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            final SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password);
            log("message", message);
            byte[] cipherText = encrypt(key, ivBytes, message.getBytes(CHARSET));
            //NO_WRAP is important as was getting \n at the end
            String encoded = String.valueOf(Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_PADDING ));
            log("Base64.NO_WRAP", encoded);
            return encoded;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
                Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException ", e);
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * More flexible AES encrypt that doesn't encode
     * @param key AES key typically 128, 192 or 256 bit
     * @param iv Initiation Vector
     * @param message in bytes (assumed it's already been decoded)
     * @return Encrypted cipher text (not encoded)
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if something goes wrong during encryption
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv, final byte[] message)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);//, ivSpec
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message);
        log("cipherText", cipherText);
        return cipherText;
    }


    /**
     * Decrypt and decode ciphertext using 256-bit AES with key generated from password
     *
     * @param password used to generated key
     * @param base64EncodedCipherText the encrpyted message encoded with base64
     * @return message in Plain text (String UTF-8)
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if there's an issue decrypting
     */
    public static String decrypt(final String password, String base64EncodedCipherText)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {

        try {
            final SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password);
            log("base64EncodedCipherText", base64EncodedCipherText);
            byte[] decodedCipherText = Base64.decode(base64EncodedCipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
            log("decodedCipherText", decodedCipherText);
            byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(key, ivBytes, decodedCipherText);
            log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);
            String message = new String(decryptedBytes, CHARSET);
            log("message", message);
            return message;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
                Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException ", e);
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * More flexible AES decrypt that doesn't encode
     *
     * @param key AES key typically 128, 192 or 256 bit
     * @param iv Initiation Vector
     * @param decodedCipherText in bytes (assumed it's already been decoded)
     * @return Decrypted message cipher text (not encoded)
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if something goes wrong during encryption
     */
    public static byte[] decrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv, final byte[] decodedCipherText)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE );
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);//, ivSpec
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedCipherText);
        log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);
        return decryptedBytes;
    }




    private static void log(String what, byte[] bytes) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + bytes.length + "] [" + bytesToHex(bytes) + "]");
    }

    private static void log(String what, String value) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + value.length() + "] [" + value + "]");
    }


    /**
     * Converts byte array to hexidecimal useful for logging and fault finding
     * @param bytes
     * @return
     */
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        final char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    private AESCryptt() {
    }
}
```

and you can call it like that :

```
    try {
        header = AESCryptt.encrypt("the key is fixed is this case",header);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("eee , exception during encrypt log in data . . . .");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The final bit of code: `strToDecrypt = "tATTXSdXI4w0oiu/fzgpyA=="` seems to have a base64 encoding, notice the trailing `==` characters. This makes sense since encryption is **data byte oriented, not string oriented**.

Base64 `"tATTXSdXI4w0oiu/fzgpyA=="`
hexadecimal: `B404D35D2757238C34A22BBF7F3829C8` (16 bytes).

You need to decode the Base64 to data bytes for the code:

```
AES.setKey("");
final String strToDecrypt = "tATTXSdXI4w0oiu/fzgpyA==";
AES.decryptbyte(toBytes(strToDecrypt.toCharArray()));
```

Also note that the above code has an empty string for a key, that is an error.

Comment: the response from server is in the Base64 encoding , and I put it in String then array of byte to decrypt it , and in this case I get exception , advice how to deal with out String .
and about Base64 I test it in the site : http://aesencryption.net/ you can try it
and the key is pre-defined .setKey("") just to set the pre-defined key 
check setKey() above  .
advice please .

Comment: Encryption primitives take in data bytes and produce data bytes. There are some implementations that add encodings prior to and/or after but that is not the encryption part. It seems it is the encoding  part you seem to be having trouble with. You really need to take the time to learn the details of strings and their encodings, Base64 and why it is used, hexadecimal and plain data bytes.

Comment: I solve it , I fix this By changing the Encryption type to AES/ECB/ZerobytePaddding , that make problems with  Base64 and byte[ ]
converting and do the decryption operation .

Comment: That can not fix it because PKCS#5 padding was used for encryption: `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`, All that does is turn off the removel of the padding and thus any potential padding error.